# ember-cp-validations - how to display error messages when there's no loss of focus before submit?

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-cp-validations

Using [ember-cp-validations](https://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/docs/modules/Basic.html) typically involves validating each property as the corresponding form element loses focus. If validation fails an error message is displayed.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="">
      {{  input type="text"
          value=item.name
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="The name of the Guest"
          focus-out=(action (mut nameError) true)
      }}
    </div>
    {{#if nameError}}
      <div class="text-danger">
        {{v-get item 'name' 'message'}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
```

This is the approach demonstrated in the online-demo (https://embermap.com/video/ember-cp-validations) however if the user enters the form and immediately hits a button that submits the form then the messages are never displayed (because focus-out never fires).

The approach demonstrated uses the object returned from validate() which is fine but in that case I would like a way to fire the validation on all form elements in order that the error messages are displayed (something to put where "Invoke all validations ..." is shown below).

```
export default Component.extend({
  actions:{
    buttonClicked(theguest) {
      theguest.validate()
        .then(({ validations }) => {
          if(validations.get('isValid'))
          {
            this.sendAction('action', theguest);
          }
          else
          {
            //Invoke all validations in order that
            //any which fail validation will show
            //their error message
          }
        })
    }
  }
});
```

What's a neat way to do this ? Thank you.